# Flash Lite 1.1 substring question

Tags: flash, string, flashlite

Could you tell me why both lines print out `a`?
`trace(substring("asd", 0, 1)); // == "a"`
`trace(substring("asd", 1, 1)); // == "a"`
(*this* prints out `s`:
`trace(substring("asd", 2, 1)); // == "s"`)

Does in Flash Lite 1.x the index start with 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract from
http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary701.html

```
Availability
Flash Player 4. This function has been deprecated in favor of String.substr .

Description
String function; extracts part of a string. This function is 1-based, 
whereas the String object methods are 0-based.
```